# IPython - How to step into library code without debug script

Tags: python, ipython

If I need to view the stack or step within a library I can do this

```
In [1]: run -d script.py
ipdb> b some_library:nnn
ipdb> c
> path/to/some_library.py(nnn).function
   nnn
   ...
```

But if I want to do the same directly on the console without using a script.

For instance

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
In [2]: user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Now to step into the call `user.email_user` I have tried

```
In [3]: debug
ipdb> b socket:nnn
ipdb> user.email_user('test', 'test message')
```

But it does not break at the line in socket.py. Given how many options there are with ipython, I feel like I am missing something obvious in not being able to do this directly from the console rather than writing a script to step through.